# SQL Increment based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I need to assign a number sequence to, then have the number sequence restarts to 1 again based on a value in another column.

Here is my table:

| Date | Name | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | Test1 | 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | Test2 | NULL |
| 03/12/2022 | Test3 | NULL |
| 04/12/2022 | Test4 | NULL |
| 05/12/2022 | Test5 | 1 |
| 06/12/2022 | Test6 | NULL |
| 07/12/2022 | Test7 | 1 |
| 08/12/2022 | Test8 | NULL |

What I need is to add an "Instance" column to the end, this column simply continues the number sequence until it hits a row with a 1 in the "Indicator" column again then it resets.

So my desired outcome would be:

| Date | Name | Indicator | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | Test1 | 1 | 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | Test2 | NULL | 2 |
| 03/12/2022 | Test3 | NULL | 3 |
| 04/12/2022 | Test4 | NULL | 4 |
| 05/12/2022 | Test5 | 1 | 1 |
| 06/12/2022 | Test6 | NULL | 2 |
| 07/12/2022 | Test7 | 1 | 1 |
| 08/12/2022 | Test8 | NULL | 2 |

I've tried playing aound with `DENSE_RANK() over (Order by Date)`

But I understandly end up with this:

| Date | Name | Indicator | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | Test1 | 1 | 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | Test2 | NULL | 2 |
| 03/12/2022 | Test3 | NULL | 3 |
| 04/12/2022 | Test4 | NULL | 4 |
| 05/12/2022 | Test5 | 1 | 1 |
| 06/12/2022 | Test6 | NULL | 6 |
| 07/12/2022 | Test7 | 1 | 1 |
| 08/12/2022 | Test8 | NULL | 8 |

The sequence carries on, it does not reset at the 1 (in the indicator column).

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting technologies. I've removed the 2 tags and added a generic one; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: Did you miss to show the time of your date or which purpose should your "ORDER BY date" have? According to your sample data, the date is identic in each row. You need to apply a safe order. So how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing out the above errors, now corrected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
select x.*, row_number() over(partition by g order by date) as instance
from (select t.*, sum(indicator) over(order by date) as g from t) x
```

Result:

```
 Date        Name   Indicator  g  instance 
 ----------- ------ ---------- -- -------- 
 2022-01-12  Test1  1          1  1        
 2022-02-12  Test2  null       1  2        
 2022-03-12  Test3  null       1  3        
 2022-04-12  Test4  null       1  4        
 2022-05-12  Test5  1          2  1        
 2022-06-12  Test6  null       2  2        
 2022-07-12  Test7  1          3  1        
 2022-08-12  Test8  null       3  2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qluY5TR7).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much - works perfectly, even has "g" which shows the Occurrence - this was my next question :)